# how to restrict landscape mode for websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, responsive-design

I have my website and want to prevent landscape mode. I want to keep users restricted to potrait mode as I have custom headers that uses around 100px space of the screen in fixed position.

Also, I want this to applied to devices below 777px of screen width.

Guys, please, let me know if it is possible, if yes then how. When I use the code that have been used for marking this as duplicate I get this problem[image: it doesnot take the wdth properly at all] as in screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

Use css media queries to show a sign to turn the device:

```
#turn {
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  #turn {
    display:block;
  }
}

<div id="turn">
  Please turn your device
</div>
```

Comment: I want to restrict the user from using landscape, and be restricted to potrait mode only. If I wanted to show that message then, I could've done it earlier.

Comment: @Abhishek Dhanraj Shahdeo: i dont now a better way and i wanted to show you a possible workaround

Comment: thanks buddy, but what I am looking for is something different. If you come across any solution then please do let me know.

Comment: Showing a message saying that they need to use portrait mode is the best way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo - You are not doing a good job of defining your problem.  Why do you want to restrict the user from choosing their interface?  You are not going to be able to stop them from turning their phone into landscape mode.  That is an internal hardware/software configuration inside iPhone/Safari `-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations`.  It is your job as the developer to provide accessibility to all cases that are possible.  If you don't want to provide that accessibility, then the user will learn to use the website as you intended or they won't use it at all.

Comment: @bdparrish - My website has some fixed content which takes a lot space and user cannot view other contents properly due to that much space already occupied, so I want the user to be on potrait mode itself rather than on landscape to add this to his user experience.

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo - seems like your UI is restrictive, so I go back to users will learn to use portrait only or they won't use the site.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try something like this:

```
@media (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 777px) {
  html {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  }
}
```

But showing a message to rotate would be much more user friendly. Some people find it hard to use the portrait mode.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem with javascript if you'd like.
For testing purposes, you can add the following code to your page:

```
window.onresize = function (event) {
    console.log('resizing!');
    console.log(`new size: w${window.innerWidth} h${window.innerHeight}`);
    if(window.innerWidth < 777) {
        // do something
    }
    if(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The value returned by `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` is a Number, so you can do calculations with it.

Comment: Its not about resizing, it is about a user opening the website in a device with landscape mode. And that needs to be restricted.